# new to OpenGLes, a few questions

Tags: opengl-es

i am starting out with opengles coming from old opengl.
i see there is no immediate mode anymore. so functions like glVertex glTexCoord are missing, right?

instead i have to use vertexarrays. right?

how can i modify the values of those arrays each frame?

for example, if i want to animate the texture coordinates, in old OpenGL i did:

```
  glTexCoord2f(x*time, y*time);
```

how can i achieve a similar effect with vertex arrays?

thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with altering the vertex array directly?

Comment: i dont use arrays i use floatbuffers mostly. isnt it performance wise bad, to iterate to the value you want to change every frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update the arrays you pass to gl*Pointer, and draw again.

If you use VBOs, you'll need to update the VBO contents also.

Comment: If this is done every frame make sure that the VBO is set to GL_STREAM_DRAW.

Answer (score 2):

if all you want to do is scroll the texture, there are direct ways to modify the texture coordinates as they go through the pipeline.

```
glMatrixMode( GL_TEXTURE );
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(...);
glMatrixMode(...);
```

In general, cases where actual texcoord data should really change (as in because you want to apply a non-uniform transformation to them) are rare.

Comment: @Mk12: Huh ? we're talking GL ES here, and I assume he meant ES 1.0, but he did not specify. on ES 2.0, you'd just do the transformation in the vertex shader...